# The set $L^2 (G) = {f : G → C}$ forms a vector space over C?

Tags: group-theory, convolution

> If you write $G = \{g_1, g_2, . . . , g_n\}$, then you can identify a function on G
> by a vector with $n$ components. The j-th component is f(gj ), for each $j = 1, 2, . . . , n.$
> Addition of functions is just vector addition, and similarly for scalar multiplication.
> Forgetting about scalar multiplication, this shows $L^2(G)$ is an abelian group under $+$.
> For $f, g \in L^2(G)$, define the convolution of $f$ and $g$, denoted $f ∗ g$ by
> $(f * g)(x) =  \sum_{a,b \in G} f(a)g(b)$
> for $x \in G$ with $ab = x$.

I need to show that $f ∗ g \in L^2(G)$, but I'm having a hard time understanding the notation of convolution in this definition.

Comment: The definition of $f * g$ in the quoted text is very awkward. A better phrasing would be $\sum_{a, b\in G, ab = x} f(a) g(b)$ or, even better $\sum_{a \in G} f(a) g(a^{-1} x)$.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to show $f * g \in L^2(G)$ to show $L^2(G)$ is a vector space. Remember, vector multiplication is not something one can do in a general vector space (only vector addition, and multiplication of a scalar with a vector). Vector spaces with an additional vector multiplication operation, that satisfy certain "reasonable" axioms (and convolution does) are known as *algebras*. Also, showing $f * g \in L^2(G)$ is a simple as noting that it's a function from $G$ to $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your head around this, I think you'll need an example. Actually calculating this takes some time, but hopefully you'll appreciate the definition of $f * g$, and how it's a function.

For our example, consider the group $G = S_3$ (whose elements I'll notate in cycle notation). Let us define $f$ and $g$ by:

\begin{align*}
f(e) &= 1 \\
f(\pmatrix{1&2}) &= -i \\
f(\pmatrix{1&3}) &= 1+i \\
f(\pmatrix{2&3}) &= 1 \\
f(\pmatrix{1&2&3}) &= 2-i \\
f(\pmatrix{1&3&2}) &= 1+6i \\
g(e) &= 0 \\
g(\pmatrix{1&2}) &= 2 \\
g(\pmatrix{1&3}) &= -i-1 \\
g(\pmatrix{2&3}) &= 1+3i \\
g(\pmatrix{1&2&3}) &= 0 \\
g(\pmatrix{1&3&2}) &= -3.
\end{align*}
These are just two functions in $L^2(G)$. Note that there's no restriction on what values we can assign to each group element, so long as they're all complex (even though I opted for Gaussian integers, to simplify calculation.

Let's compute $f * g$ at a couple of values. What about $(f * g)(e)$? We need to find all *ordered* pairs $a, b$ in $S_3$ whose product is $e$. That is, all the inverse pairs. Note that all the transpositions are self-inverse, as is $e$. The cycles are inverse to each other. This means that:
\begin{align*}
(f * g)(e) &= f(e)g(e) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 2})g(\pmatrix{1 & 2}) + f(\pmatrix{2 & 3})g(\pmatrix{2 & 3}) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 3})g(\pmatrix{1 & 3}) \\
&+ f(\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3})g(\pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2}) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2})g(\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3}) \\
&= 1 \cdot 0 + (-i) \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot (1 + 3i) + (1 + i) \cdot (-i - 1) + (2 - i) \cdot (-3) + (1 + 6i) \cdot 0 \\
&= 0 - 2i + 1 + 3i - 2i - 6 + 3i + 0 \\
&= -5 + 2i.
\end{align*}

That's just the value of the convolution at one point! We can also find, for example, $(f * g)(\pmatrix{1 & 2})$. We therefore need to find all the pairs $(a, b)$ of group elements that multiply to $ab = \pmatrix{1 & 2}$. These are,
\begin{align*}
(a, b) = \; &(e, \pmatrix{1 & 2}), (\pmatrix{1 & 2}, e), (\pmatrix{1 & 3}, \pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3}), (\pmatrix{2 & 3}, \pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2}), \\
&(\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3}, \pmatrix{2 & 3}), (\pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2}, \pmatrix{1 & 3}).
\end{align*}
Hopefully you can verify that each pair $(a, b)$ has the product $\pmatrix{1 & 2}$. Then, the convolution is given by
\begin{align*}
(f * g)(\pmatrix{1 & 2}) &= f(e)g(\pmatrix{1 & 2}) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 2})g(e) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 3})g(\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3}) \\
&+ f(\pmatrix{2 & 3})g(\pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2}) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3})g(\pmatrix{2 & 3}) + f(\pmatrix{1 & 3 & 2})g(\pmatrix{1 & 3}) \\
&= 1 \cdot 2 + (-i) \cdot 0 + (1 + i) \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot (-3) + (2 - i) \cdot (1 + 3i) + (1 + 6i) \cdot (-i - 1) \\
&= 2 + 0 + 0 - 3 + 5 + 5i + 5 - 7i \\
&= 9 - 2i.
\end{align*}
As you can see, the scalar you get depends on the group element $x$ you feed it. And, hopefully, you can see how you'd continue this procedure for other $x \in S_3$ (or even, how you would do this for more general finite groups).